# Motherboard recommendation for CPU and ECC-registered buffered memory combination

Tags: processor, motherboard, memory, compatibility, intel

We have a couple of ECC-registered (buffered) RAMs (2x Samsung 32GB 2Rx4 PC4-2666V-RB2) as well as a CPU (Intel XEON W-1250 SRH48 3.3GHz X113D365). We couldn't find a compatible motherboard that works with both.

Considering the rams are expensive, we should find a proper motherboard/CPU combination for it.

I would like to know if you have any suggestions on what motherboard to buy that works with both.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

**Update:** For us, it doesn't matter if the motherboard supports ECC or not, any motherboard that matches this CPU+RAM combination works for me.

Update 2: We need a motherboard that supports "Buffered" memories, not unbuffered. Unless you give me a way to make a buffered memory work with a motherboard that only supports unbuffered memories.

[image: CPU]

[image: RAM]

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU requires a socket FCLGA1200. All of these chipsets have this socket:

- Intel Z490 / Z590
- Intel B460 / B560
- Intel H410 / H510
- Intel H470
- Intel W480

The memory you have is requires a DDR4 slot. Although some non ECC main boards are, while not supporting ECC *functionality*, still able to accept ECC memory, [others may not](https://www.integralmemory.com/faq1/can-i-install-an-ecc-dimm-on-a-non-ecc-motherboard/) (depending on manufacturer BIOS support).

It's therefore safest to get one with out-of-the-box ECC support. Of the chipsets above, only the **W480** [supports ECC](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15863/the-intel-w480-motherboard-overview-lga1200-for-xeon-w-1200). In that same article, Anandtech additionally provides a list of main boards with this chipset, which, although two years old, based on local market research still seems representative (or rather, I haven't found any additional main boards available beyond the ones below):

- **ASRock W480 Creator**
- ASRock Rack W480D4U
- ASUS Pro WS W480-Ace
- DFI CMS310-W480
- **GIGABYTE W480 Vision D**
- GIGABYTE W480 Vision W
- GIGABYTE W480M Vision W
- Supermicro X12SCZ-TLN4F
- Supermicro X12SCZ-F
- **Supermicro X12SAE**

I'm not sure which country or region you are in, but based on my local availability I've highlighted three that are still available here with at least three different vendors. I would personally choose a Supermicro or Gigabyte over an ASRock. All of the three highlighted have at least two DDR4 slots.

**UPDATE:**

I missed that this refers to **buffered** ECC, which is the proverbial different ball game altogether. No main board appears to be available that combines both a socket 1200 CPU *and* buffered ECC DDR4 modules.

To clarify: some non ECC supporting main boards are able to run with regular ECC (chipset AND firmware version dependent, and they will not be able to take advantage of ECC features), however *buffered* ECC needs to be specifically supported, or it will not operate ([source: Kingston](https://support.kingston.com/Server-Memory/2194163861/What-is-the-difference-between-registered-unbuffered-ECC-and-fully-buffered-memory.htm)):

> Fully buffered memory cannot be used in a computer that takes
> registered memory or vise versa.

It therefore looks like the answer is unfortunately that **no**, this combination is not possible.

Comment: Thanks but ASRock W480 Creator is not supporting buffered memories (our memory is buffered) therefore it won't be able to run ours

Comment: Same for ASUS Pro WS W480-Ace

Comment: also GIGABYTE W480 Vision D don't support buffered memories

Comment: In overal, looks like non of these main boards support buffered memories such as mine, therefore won't be able to run with the combination.

Comment: Alternatively, do you know any way to make a buffered memory work with a motherboard that only supports unbuffered memories?

Comment: You're right. I did some more digging, and for as far as I can tell the combination of socket 1200 and *registered/buffered* ECC DDR4 support (also, at that exact timing) does not appear. I assume these two bits of hardware of yours have not worked together before? You may have to consider getting either a different CPU, or different memory (or both, and end up with two machines rather than one).

Comment: No, they are from 2 different worlds ... thank for your investigations anyways :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Apologies for being the bearer of bad news!